# When we burn a wood it burns with flame although it do not contain any gaseous substance

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, physical-chemistry, combustion

In books it is given that flame is only produced when gaseous substance burn but when dry wood is burnt it also burn with flame.why.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Physics of a burning log of firewood](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39396/)

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap a small (5g, a teaspoon) piece of wood (or sawdust/shavings) in aluminium foil and heat it (eg. on a kitchen stovetop) you will see flames. This is caused by the wood (carbohydrates) decomposing to carbon and [wood alcohol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanol), which is flammable. If you open the foil afterwards you will find charcoal (mainly carbon). In a wood fire (without the foil) the charcoal will also combust, but will not contribute to the flame.

Comment: I woke in the night thinking that I had better define "small", for safety reasons.